# I deleted the “/etc/passwd” file and cannot log in

Tags: login, users, etc

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Unfortunately I deleted my `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/passwd` files and am not able to log in again.

How can I fix this?

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/411514/how-to-recover-a-deleted-etc-passwd-file and https://askubuntu.com/questions/147631/i-deleted-the-etc-passwd-file-and-cannot-log-in

Comment: Back away from the computer.